# php_dio & php_win32service won't work on wamp server 2.5

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to use php_dio & php_win32service because I want to query COM10 on my server using php and also get status & restart some of my win services.

Although I'm using the correct dlls (for PHP 5.5 X64 thread safe) I keep getting warning icon on the extensions and there is no error on php log.

I'm clueless what can be done.

please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Warning icon is presented in that menu for 2 possible reasons

- The `extension=php_xxx.dll` exists in the php.ini file but the dll does not exist in the `\ext` folder.
- The dll exists in `\ext` folder but the `extension=php_xxx.dll` line does not exist in the php.ini file.

So which did you forget to do?

Also remember there are 2 `php.ini` files :-

- The one in `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` is used by PHP CLI only
- The one you can edit using the wampmanager->PHP->php.ini menus which is used by when running under Apache.

You say you have used the correct dll's but just to be sure for WAMPServer 2.5 using Apache2.2.9 you need the Thread Safe + VC11 compiled versions

Comment: You sir are a genius !
I didn't add the extension in the correct php.ini file.

Comment: Or maybe I have also made this same mistake in the past.

Comment: But now I find different problem , I have USB GPS connectec to computer , it is identified as COM6 , but when I try using dio_open('com6:', O_RDWR); I get error that dio_open(): cannot open file com6: with flags 2 and permissions 0: Permission denied